# Java get objects elements from List<Objects> and add to new ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, latitude-longitude

I am quite new to Java, but I seem to having a brain fog at the moment as I should be able to do this.

I have a List that includes quite a few items including Latitude and longitude elements, see model class shown. I want to retrieve just Lat and long doubles elements and add to a new Array List whilst iterating through.

I tried using the code below and get an empty ArrayList back. I know it is probably something very obviously simple I am getting incorrect, but I cannot see the wood for the trees at the moment!

```
ArrayList<LatLng> markerArrayList; *(Global variable) *

markerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

for (OrmeauModel list : ormeauList) {

                    double markerLat = list.getMarker_lat();
                    double markerLong = list.getMarker_long();
                    LatLng latLong = new LatLng(markerLat, markerLong);
                    markerArrayList.add(latLong);
                }

**the Model class has getters from the following constructor**

public OrmeauModel(int marker_id, double marker_lat, double marker_long, String description, int image) {
        this.marker_id = marker_id;
        this.marker_lat = marker_lat;
        this.marker_long = marker_long;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
    }
```

Comment: You have missed out some code showing how you get this conclusion or reproduce, it needs better example. Using a debugger or adding println to show values of list before, in and after the loop should explain.

Comment: Neither the text nor the code snippet gives even the first hint in answering the question. There's nothing particularly problematic about your code (other than the horrifically confusing name `list` for a single element from a list, and not using java conventions for naming, and using a 'global variable' which is a bad idea - but these are style points, they have absolutely nothing to do with the problem you're running into).